# Complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am a newbie to complex numbers so please bear with me if i ask some very naive question.,

So i was trying to solve my class tutorials and the very first question is,

> Show that $\operatorname{Re}(iz) = - \operatorname{Im}(z)$

I know the basics of complex numbers like addition, subtraction, conjugates but can't seem to figure this out. Can someone explain me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can write $z$ as $z=a+ib$, where $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ so 
$$iz= i(a+ib)= ia - b$$ 
Hence $\operatorname{Re}(iz)=-b$ . But $\operatorname{Im}(z)=b$, hence $\operatorname{Re}(iz)=-\operatorname{Im}(z)$

Answer (score 0):

Let $z = a + i b$.  Then

$$ \Re(iz) = \Re(i (a + ib)) = \Re (ia - b) = -b = - \Im(a + i b) = -\Im(z) $$